# Get normalized path for windows location in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-commons

I have a requirement where I have a path as `C:\..\bar`
for this the file bar gets created in the C drive when I use this path in SQL server.
Now on using Apache's FilenameUtils, The `normalize` method returns null as also documented.

> - C:\..\bar            -->   null

But I want

> C:\bar for C:\..\bar

Is there any way in Java to get C:\bar for C:\..\bar
I know that `..` would mean parent directory but SQL server still creates file the C drive.

The issue with using File or Path classes is that they make use of underlying Filesystem, which in my case is Unix but the path I will get will be windows absolute path.
So basically want to get rid of any redundancy like dots and slashes irrespective of the file system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getCanonicalFile`.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\\..\\bar");
        System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
    }
}
```

Comment: Any other way would be better because generally File objects are used to do operations on file whereas in this case I just want to play with the filepath and make sure no file-related operations happen.

Comment: You can use `getCanonicalPath`, which will give you back the string (as edited just now). To get the canonical path is a file related operation, if you don't want to do that then you need to do string manipulations.